# Unzipping Large Files Using Databricks PySpark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a scenario, where there are two `blob containers` belonging to two different `azure` `storage accounts`. Both containers are mounted in a `Databricks` workspace. The first container `cnt-input` has a folder with large number of `zip` files (**20K** per day), each is appx **5GB** in size. The compression ratio is 1/10, meaning that when decompressed, the result is multiple `csv` files with total size of appx. **50GB**. `Zip` files are pushed to this container on a daily basis. I would like to create a `pyspark` notebook that:

1- Process files incrementally; detect new incoming files and leave the ones already processed.

2- Take a large number of files as a batch (e.g. **20K**) and unzip it, and save the decompressed `csv` files in the second `blob` container: `cnt-output`.

3- The process should be performant and optimal (`Databricks` runtime version is 12.1, and the cluster has 8 worker nodes of type `Standard_DS3_v2`).

Comment: It's not the best use case for Databricks. Do you consider other options? See [here](https://www.frankysnotes.com/2019/02/how-to-unzip-automatically-your-files.html) for a solution using Azure Functions.

Comment: can you share what you have tried and error if you facing any issue?

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy this is actually part of a workflow, in which I process the extracted csv files in the following steps. Additionally, I would like this pipeline to be completely on Databricks, and to avoid hybrid solutions. Otherwise I could use ADF as well.

Comment: @PratikLad There is no error received. I used the command 'dbutils.fs.cp' within a for loop for copying files, and I used the shell command 'unzip' for decompressing, but I find this slow and not performant (takes around 2 hours to complete), compared to ADF which does the same in under 17 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow below approach.

Here, I am loading zip files, extract it and upload it to blob container using
auto loader concept.
Which loads data incrementally.

```
import os
import zipfile

  

def extract_zip_file(file_data):
    file_path, modificationTime,length,content = file_data
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_path.replace("dbfs:","/dbfs"), 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall("/dbfs"+output_mount_path+"csv_data")

input_mount_path = "/mnt/jgsblob/cnt-input/"
output_mount_path = "/mnt/jgsblob2/cnt-ouput/"
```

`extract_zip_file` is the function used to extract files which are read by spark
`readstream` as below.

```
query = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles").option("cloudFiles.format", "binaryFile").option("pathGlobFilter", "*.zip")\
.load(input_mount_path+"Databricks").writeStream.option("checkpointLocation", output_mount_path+"chk_point/")\
.foreachBatch(lambda batch_df, batch_id: batch_df.foreach(extract_zip_file)).start()
```

[image]

In this code, I used the format as **cloudFiles** which invokes auto loader,
and **checkpointLocation** where it stores the records which are already uploaded.

Below are the zip files in container one, that is input mount path
`input_mount_path = "/mnt/jgsblob/cnt-input/"`

[image]

Output:
Below are files extracted in container 2, that is output mount path.
`output_mount_path = "/mnt/jgsblob2/cnt-ouput/"`

[image]

Here, you can see initially the **cosmetics.csv** and **voted-kaggle-dataset** are created at **11:51** and I uploaded new zip file, then at **11:55**  **gold.csv** loaded,
even though previous zip files contain in container one.

Make sure to use the correct node type according to your input data size.
Because I have tested this for small size files.